# Understanding of Promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I want to implement `deferred` with native `Promise` and made some experiments.

```
var p, _p;
p = new Promise((t, f) => {
  p.resolve = t; 
  p.reject = f;
  _p = p; // let's save it into global
});
p.then(
  console.log.bind(console, 'ok'), 
  console.log.bind(console, 'fail')
);
console.log(p === _p);      // false!
console.log(typeof p.resolve, typeof _p.resolve); // 'undefined' 'function'
_p.resolve(42); // 'ok' 42
```

What `p` was pointed inside the promise function?
Why it is some another instance? How can I extend returned one?

Comment: "ReferenceError: outer_p is not defined

Comment: `p` is undefined inside the executor function.

Comment: `outer_p` should probably be `_p` and then you're script works as expected. `_p` will be `undefined`

Comment: Yes, sorry. I rename it for simplify. Just missed one

Comment: @robertklep, but `_p` is a `Promise` with `resolve` and `reject` methods after all.

Comment: Not for me it isn't, it's undefined. Tested with Node v4 and v6. How are you running your code? Is `Promise` a native promise implementation, or is it provided by a library?

Comment: @vp_arth I don't see how, with the code as you post it, `p` _cannot_ be undefined inside the executor callback. It's like having the result of a function before the function has finished executing (it's the equivalent of `var value = void function() { console.log('value =', value); return 123}()`)

Comment: Oh, thanks to @robertklep)) inner `p` was always from previous calls. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What p was pointed inside the promise function?

When you're setting your `p` in promise, you're referencing to a global `p` (the one you declared).

```
var p, _p; // declared, but not value set
p = new Promise((t, f) => {
  console.log(p); //undefined
  console.log(window.hasOwnProperty("p")); //true
  window.p = 3;
  console.log(p); // 3
});

console.log(p); // promise
```

As you haven't set any value for your `p` before promise call, it's value is `undefined`.

> Why it is some another instance? How can I extend returned one?

Because in the time when you're setting properties on `p`, your call to promise hasn't finished yet. Browser has first executes arguments  you are sending to promise (that is your arrow function) , then calls your promise with arguments and only after that it assigns return value of promise to variable `p` (and overwrites any changes you made to `p` inside your arrow function).

The only way to extend the returned Promise object is to extend it after it has been created and assigned to your `p`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys for point my fault.
I ended up with followed implementation:

```
function Deferred() {
  this.promise = new Promise((ok, fail) => {
    this.resolve = ok;
    this.reject = fail;
  });
}

!function() {
  var p = new Deferred();
  p.promise.then(
    console.log.bind(console, 'ok'), 
    console.log.bind(console, 'fail')
  );
  p.resolve(42); // ok 42
}();
```

Extending of `Promise` object was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

`p` does get reject and resolve functions appended to it when you define them:

```
p = new Promise((t, f) => {
  console.log(p) // it is not defined as a promise
  p.resolve = t; 
  p.reject = f; 
  console.log(p) // p now is defined AND has resolve and reject defined in it
  _p = p // _p now is a promise object with resolve and reject defined 
});
```

However, the moment you finish creating your promise, it will lose all the extra elements you've added to it. If you want to extend your `p` for whatever reason, you can do it after the promise has been created. For instance

```
p = new Promise((t, f) => {
  console.log(p) // it is already defined as a promise
  p.resolve = t; 
  p.reject = f; 
  console.log(p) // p now has resolve and reject defined in it too
  _p = p // _p now is a promise object with resolve and reject defined 
});
p.extraExtension = "hello"
console.log(p); // at this stage your p will have extraExtension extended to it, but its attributes and status as a Promise are also there. However, simply defining `p.resolve` and `p.reject` wouldn't make them function as proper resolve and reject methods for the promise.
```

Promises already have `resolve` and `reject` defined in them:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject

The way to call them is to simply refer to them inside the promise object:

```
p = new Promise((t, f) => {
  console.log(p) // it is already defined as a promise
  resolve(t); // the promise will now resolve. Similarly you can call reject() here.
});
```

For more information refer to the official documentation here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

You can see all the inherent methods and properties of a Promise object there.

Comment: `it is already defined as a promise`. Just because we don't use clean scope. It was defined on previous call in the same REPL. Last snippet about: may be not `resolve(t)` but just `t()` ? Anyway, my target was `deferred` implementation. Read my answer for details.